# SQL Server : query to get MINUTE of date in specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server

The below query returns MINUTE of certain hour of a date.

For example if date value ='2017-07-19 05:50:00.000', it will returns `50`.

My issue is I need to get MINUTE in specified date not all the dates that exist in the table.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(MINUTE, ClockOut) 
FROM
    [dbo].[Attendance] 
WHERE
    DATEPART(HOUR, ClockOut) = '5'
```

The query I tried to return minutes only in `'2017-07-19'` and it returns no record.

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(MINUTE, ClockOut) 
FROM
    [dbo].[Attendance] 
WHERE 
    DATEPART(HOUR, ClockOut) = '5' AND ClockOut = '2017-07-19'
```

Sample data

Clock Out

```
2017-07-19 05:50:00.000
2017-07-20 05:51:00.000
2017-07-21 05:52:00.000
```

I need to return minutes at hour 5 only on this date `'2017-07-19'`

Comment: Could you provide a sample data?

Comment: i just added the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing datetime to date that's why it is not returning your desired result.

```
SELECT  DATEPART(MINUTE, ClockOut)
FROM    [dbo].[Attendance]
WHERE   DATEPART(HOUR, ClockOut) = '5'
        AND CAST(ClockOut AS DATE) = '2017-07-19';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ClockOut columns contains a `DateTime` (2017-07-19 12:03:42) so it's value is never exact equal to a date (2017-07-19). Use a range instead so the Query Plan can use an potential index on Clockout. Casting to a Date or using `DatePart` rules this out causing longer execution times if the number of rows is large.

```
SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE, ClockOut) 
FROM   [dbo].[Attendance] 
WHERE  DATEPART(HOUR, ClockOut) = 5 
AND    ClockOut BETWEEN '2017-07-19' 
                    AND '2017-07-20' -- start of next day
```

[working demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/703081)

Answer (score 0):

If you use ClockOut='2017-07-19' it's like write '2017-07-19 0:00:00'. Try to use DataPart (yyyy, Clockout)=2017 and DataPary (MM, Clockout)=7 and DataPart (dd, Clockout)=19